# Как удалить veracrypt из автозагрузки?

Tags: шифрование, диск, veracrypt

Я расшифровал диск, но в начале все еще появляется" введите пароль", я нажимаю Esc вхожу в Windows. Как удалить эту начальную запись загрузчика veracrypt? Попытка удалить его не помогла! Этого нет в автоматической загрузке! Я даже попытался переустановить Windows, она все равно осталась!

Comment: Вероятно, надо его снова установить и порыть настройки.

Comment: Попытался в настройках все галочки убрал! Всё равно есть вот это в начале запись "Veracrypt bootleader", "Enter password"!